# How to make a GUI for my TensorFlow chatbot?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tkinter

I have a chat bot up and running in command line but I want to give it an GUI. How can I do that? Please help me out here as I have an event with this tomorrow. Would really appreciate it. Just a simple UI with a field to type the message and then the bot's reply would be sufficient. Just give me an idea of how I can achieve this.

```
    import pickle
    import json
    import random
    import tflearn
    import tensorflow
    import numpy
    import nltk
   from nltk.stem.lancaster import LancasterStemmer
   stemmer = LancasterStemmer()


 with open("intents.json") as file:
     data = json.load(file)

try:
   with open("data.pickle", "rb") as f:
       words, labels, training, output = pickle.load(f)
except:
  words = []
  labels = []
  docs_x = []
  docs_y = []

for intent in data["intents"]:
    for pattern in intent["patterns"]:
        wrds = nltk.word_tokenize(pattern)
        words.extend(wrds)
        docs_x.append(wrds)
        docs_y.append(intent["tag"])

    if intent["tag"] not in labels:
        labels.append(intent["tag"])

words = [stemmer.stem(w.lower()) for w in words if w != "?"]
words = sorted(list(set(words)))

labels = sorted(labels)

training = []
output = []

out_empty = [0 for _ in range(len(labels))]

for x, doc in enumerate(docs_x):
    bag = []

    wrds = [stemmer.stem(w.lower()) for w in doc]

    for w in words:
        if w in wrds:
            bag.append(1)
        else:
            bag.append(0)

    output_row = out_empty[:]
    output_row[labels.index(docs_y[x])] = 1

    training.append(bag)
    output.append(output_row)

training = numpy.array(training)
output = numpy.array(output)

with open("data.pickle", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump((words, labels, training, output), f)

tensorflow.reset_default_graph()

net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, len(training[0])])
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8) 
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, len(output[0]), activation="softmax")
net = tflearn.regression(net)

model = tflearn.DNN(net) 

try:
   model.load("model.tflearn")
except:
   model.fit(training, output, n_epoch=1000, batch_size=8, 
   show_metric=True)
   model.save("model.tflearn")


def bag_of_words(s, words):
   bag = [0 for _ in range(len(words))]

   s_words = nltk.word_tokenize(s)
   s_words = [stemmer.stem(word.lower()) for word in s_words]

for se in s_words:
    for i, w in enumerate(words):
        if w == se:
            bag[i] = 1

return numpy.array(bag)


def chat():
   print("Start talking with the bot (type quit to stop)!")
   while True:
      inp = input("You: ")
      if inp.lower() == "quit":
          break

     results = model.predict([bag_of_words(inp, words)])[0]
     results_index = numpy.argmax(results)
     tag = labels[results_index]

     if results[results_index] > 0.8:
         for tg in data["intents"]:
             if tg['tag'] == tag:
                 responses = tg['responses']
         print(random.choice(responses))
     else:
        print("I didn't get that, please check the question and try 
 again.")


 chat()
```

Comment: Use TCP Sockets and PyQt

Comment: I have no idea of what that is, and I have a project due tomorrow. I know its a long shot but could you do it for me? I will be running it on my local machine.

Comment: I came here to recommend PyQt as well. Sorry, but I think you should try it yourself and ask for help in case you get stuck in some step. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this github repo, 
https://github.com/dmitrizzle/chat-bubble